# What is 'Native Type' for 'char*' in dart FFI?

Tags: dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I have a function like this in `C` language:

```c
char* getString() {
    return "SOME_STRING";
}
```

now I want to invoke it by `FFI` in `dart`, and this is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ffi';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  print('${getString()}');
}

final DynamicLibrary nativeAppTokenLib = Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open('lib_native_get_string.so')
    : DynamicLibrary.process();

final String Function() getString = nativeAppTokenLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<*** Function()>>('getString')
    .asFunction();
```

I wonder what should I put instead of `***` as the native type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import "package:ffi/ffi.dart";

...

final Pointer<Utf8> Function() _getString = nativeAppTokenLib
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Pointer<Utf8> Function()>>('getString')
    .asFunction();
String getString() => _getString().toDartString();
```

This uses [`package:ffi`](https://pub.dev/documentation/ffi/latest/ffi/ffi-library.html)'s `Utf8` type to represent characters. The [toDartString](https://pub.dev/documentation/ffi/latest/ffi/Utf8Pointer/toDartString.html) extension method on `Pointer<Utf8>` is the intended way to convert those to a string.